# Node JS pdf file returns corrupted

Tags: node.js, rest, pdf, character-encoding

I’ve been having an issue retuning a PDF from an API.

When I call the API though Postman it works perfectly and I get a correct pdf, But when I call the service through Node JS I get a a PDF with the correct number of pages however the content is corrupted so the pages are blank.

I have been comparing the contents of the correct pdf and the blank pdf using a text comparison website.

I found that sending the response in a Buffer reduces the number of characters that are different to the correct file, however I am still getting extra characters.

eg.

<�L*f3d%6��\��dH@�Ǆ���W>�I�P��b��9'ԏ6�� (Correct)
<�L*f3d%6��\��dH@�Ǆ���W>���I�P��b��9'ԏ6�� (Corrupted)

Any ideas where I’m going wrong?

---

*Serivce call*

```
const data = await instance.get('pdfreport');
const file = new Buffer(data.data, 'utf8');
return file;
```

*Controller*

```
const getPdf = await req.services.pdf.get();
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', getPdf.length);
res.send(getPdf);
```

Comment: I believe the type of pdf should be ' application/pdf ' instead of 'utf8'

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be the encoding? I do have `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', getPdf.length);` set in the controller (updated the original question to reflect this).

Comment: have you found a solution? @JoshLittlewood